# fragmenttabhost on first time could not display data

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I am trying to use fragmenttabhost that 4 tabs, but when I into first tabs could not display data on first time, however i should click other tabs then back first tab the data would be show.

i will  via API data then  display onlistview and viewpager(picture and text)  in different  tabs , but i don't understand or lose some things should to do...

**my activity:**

```
FragmentActivity extends ActionBarActivity

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        tabHost.addTab(setIndicator(this,tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG),0,"first tab",R.drawable.ic_launcher), firstFragment.class,null);
        ...
```

**my fragment:**

1 :use volley and get json data(ex:get a imagm  url )

```
FirstTabFragment extends Fragment
onAttach(Activity activity)
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        ..
        use volley and get json data(ex:get a imagm url)...
        ...}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfragment_page1, container, false);
        return rootView;`
```

2.onActivityCreated:use volley image url show some pictures to pageView widge...

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //use volley image url show some pictures on pageView widge...
    RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(tag,"myurl.get(i)"+promotionOneUrl.get(i));          
    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(promotionOneUrl.get(i),  
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {  
            @Override  
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {  
            imageView.setImageBitmap(response);}  
            }, 0, 0, Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){                       
            R.drawable.default_image);}});
    mQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

p.s.sorry for poor english

Comment: I guess the add tab is not working properly. You should add tabs seperately

Comment: Check this : http://anotepad.com/notes/5009743?first_note=1&event=create_pub#.VMR8QjWkVC0

Comment: i was add tabs separately in here, just not write add all...

Comment: Yup try the same way